# RFECV in sklearn, scores from grid_scores_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation, rfe

I am using `sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV`:

```
ref = RFECV(lr, step=1, cv =5, scoring="r2")
ref.fit(X_ndarr, y_ndarr)
print(ref.grid_scores_)
```

I get:

*[ 0.9316829   0.93472609  0.79440118 -2.37744438 -1.20559428
 -1.35899883  -0.90087801 -1.02047363 -0.54169276 **-0.08116821** 
 -0.00685128  0.1561999 -0.26433411 -0.27843449 -0.32703359 
 -0.32782641  -0.30881354  0.11878835  0.08175137  0.04300757

 0.0378917   0.04534877]*

`RFECV` removes the least important feature at each step, so the score for e.g. 10 features should be the best achieved score for any 10 features, while when I run the code below using a selected 10 feature (using another way):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(lr, X_top10_ndarr, y_ndarr, cv=5) # top10 features
```

Then I get:

*cross-validation scores:  [0.96706997 0.9653103  0.96386666 0.96017565 0.96603127]*

All of the scores are around **0.96**, while the score with 10 features from `RFECV` is **-0.08**.

What exactly is happening here?

**EDIT1**: The number of selected features is `2` and the `ranking_` is as follows:

*[ 4  7  **1**  6  3  2  8 11  5 10 21  9 12 14 13 15 16 19 18 17  **1** 20]*

Answer (score 0):

`ref.grid_scores_` represent the cross-validation scores such that grid_scores_[i] corresponds to the CV score of the i-th subset of features.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378143/6347629) answer for more understanding of these values.

Going by that explanation, the model's cv score for 10 features would be   **`-0.26433411`**

Having said that, the score is really bad since it is negative probably linear models may not be good for your data set.

one more point to note is that even will all the features, you have go only 0.9316829 which is less than 0.96.

May be set a `random_state` with StratifiedKFold and feed that as a cv param value.

Comment: thanks. I thought it would be `-0.26` too, but `n_features_` is `2`, and the 2nd item  in arr is the largest. To verify it for yourself print the `grid_scores_` for this one: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py So, I think the documentation is not accurate either! You also mentioned that LR might not be good fit, so why is it a good fit when I do LR with CV?  RFECV is supposed to give the best result among any 10 features combination. right?