# Why does Recursive Feature Elimination give different results each time in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, rfe

I am currently trying to use RFE in python to select features for a stock prediction project. Since this is a regression task (predicting close price of next 10 days) I am using `DecisionTreeRegressor` as my model in RFE. Below is my code:

```
def performRFE(x, y, minFeatures):
    rfecv = RFECV(
        estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(),
        step=1,
        cv=6,
        min_features_to_select=minFeatures
    )
    rfecv.fit(x, y)
    x = rfecv.transform(x)
    // printing which features got selected
    rfeOutput = list(zip(cols, list(rfecv.support_)))
    for feature in rfeOutput:
        print("{} : {}".format(feature[0], feature[1]))
```

I want to know if I am doing it right because for the same stock and the same set of original features, RFE gives a different result (picks a different subset of features) every time I run it. I plan to use the output of RFE in an LSTM model to predict the close price. Here `x` contains data such open,close,high,low,volume,EMAs, SMAs, RSI, etc. Is it normal to get different results from RFE each time?

Comment: Try using a decision tree like this: `DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 42)`. If it still gave you different results, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378143/14425501) answer.